# Facing configuration error while installing from source

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded vlc source [vlc-2.0.6.tar.xz](http://cznic.dl.sourceforge.net/project/vlc/2.0.6/vlc-2.0.6.tar.xz) from sourceforge.

While compiling by `./configure`, It gives following error:

```
configure: error: Could not find libmad on your system: you may get it from http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/. Alternatively you can use --disable-mad to disable the mad plugin.
```

After retrying `./configure ----disable-mad` further errors:

```
No package 'libavutil' found. Pass --disable-avcodec to ignore this error.
```

And so on. How to solve this? **Should I disable continuously with --disable ?**

How solve such configure error. **This question is not limited to vlc but widely I going to install package from source.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you following commands to solve this problem.

```
apt-get build-dep vlc
./configure
```

Ubuntu repository has also vlc.

So you can build it with following command.

```
apt-get source vlc
cd vlc-<version>
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Use `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b` to get binaries, `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -S` for a source package without using sudo.